# Scheduled mailings don't get sent

Tags: scheduling, mailing

If we schedule a mailing, they only ever say running in the status column but never get sent.  The only way they send is if we hit "execute now", so at least we know they are no email config/password issues.

I have little experience with Drupal, CiviCRM and Linux, so don't even know where to look for logs.

CiviCRM is running off Drupal on a Linux Ubuntu vm, I've found version number for CiviCRM is 4.1, Drupal is 7.34, php is 5.59 and MySQL 5.541.

How can I get the mailing delivered automatically?

EDIT:
I have checked under the scheduled jobs (administer > system settings >schedules jobs) and found this.[image]

If i click on log for the above, i get a blank web page.  The test mailing i scheduled is still sat there saying "running".

I looked at the civicrm instructions before I posted on here, but to be honest they mean nothing to me, i didnt setup civi, never used drupal so I am really trying to sort this problem.

I have run crontab -l and everything is commented out.

Please can someone help

Comment: I understand your point, but don't know where to look for the cronjob and which user it is. I checked the drupal user permissions and all authenticated users can view etc anythng civimail related. Sorry but like i say, i have no civicrm experience, no drupal and little linux. thanks

Comment: i am giong to close this ticket and open a new one and try using the forum correctly. i cannot post comment due to a reputation thing. new ticket is http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/scheduled-mailings-dont-send-civicrm4-1[enter link description here](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/scheduled-mailings-dont-send-civicrm4-1)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may not have a server cron job set up to trigger the Civi cron job.  Are your other Scheduled Jobs executing?

The documentation to reference is here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't yet have the cron job set up, or there is a problem with it. The [Scheduled jobs](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/) section of the user guide walks you through creating the job. Things may be slightly different from the docs if you're still on CiviCRM version 4.1 (which is reeeally old) but this will get you started.

Comment: The modern Scheduled Jobs was introduced in Civi 4.1, so these docs should be pretty decent - but agreed, an upgrade is in order!

Answer (score 3):

Since you say that the status is running, it sounds like the job gets started okay, meaning the cron is probably running okay.

Your ability to successfully manually execute the job points to me that you probably have permission issues.  When you manually execute the job, it runs with the permissions that you're logged-in account has.

Cron however is usually setup with a different account with its own permissions configuration.  If you look at the cron job setup you can determine the user account being used... using that, look up it's civi permissions and make sure that the appropriate permissions are given.  (Minimally these include: view all contacts,
access CiviCRM, access CiviMail)

Comment: Good observation about the status being running which shows it's probably not a cron issue.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your php is a version (5.5) that wasn't used during the civicrm 4.1 development. So perhaps the system job code isn't compatible with 5.5 (which would also be consistent with your white screen when trying to look at your system job log).

If this is the issue, there should be something in your files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog directory that confirms the problem.

There's a good chance you could work around the problem with an adjustment to your php.ini file that sets more of the backward compatibility-type flags.