# scheduled mailings dont send - civicrm4.1

Tags: civimail, cron-job, scheduling

If we schedule a mailing, they only ever say running in the status column but never get sent. The only way they send is if we hit "execute now", so at least we know they are no email config/password issues.

I have little experience with Drupal, CiviCRM and Linux, so don't even know where to look for logs.

CiviCRM is running off Drupal on a Linux Ubuntu vm, I've found version number for CiviCRM is 4.1, Drupal is 7.34, php is 5.59 and MySQL 5.541.

I have checked under the scheduled jobs (administer > system settings >schedules jobs) and found [image]

I don't know where to look for the cronjob and which user it uses though. I checked the drupal user permissions and all authenticated users can view etc anythng civimail related.

I have no civicrm experience (i didnt install this), no drupal and little linux, I would appreciate some help.  I have tried following instructions on the civi site but they are not clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your original question with the new information. This one will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I have found that, if a mailing is stuck as "running", but does correctly run when "execute now" is clicked, that you have a permissions problem.

When you "execute now" the mailing is executed using the permissions of the currently logged in user.

The cron job however usually runs as a different user. This user needs minimally to have a few permissions set: view all contacts, access CiviCRM, access CiviMail.

I would first track down your cronjob to find out what user is referenced in it.  Without more details on your hosting platform its a little difficult to help you with that.  If you have SSH access, try issuing a command line: crontab -l.  If your hosting provided gives you cpanel or similar, you may be able to view the cron jobs with that.

Comment: crontab only shows the cron jobs of the user you use for SSH-login as far as I understand, in my case "no crontab for [user]". How could you see the cron jobs of the cron user?